# Testing out of Undergraduate Major Requirements

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, undergraduate, exams, major

**Background**

I am a pending transfer student (incoming undergraduate sophomore) at various universities. I plan on pursuing a double major in math and physics.

Now, I believe that I am proficient in many of the math/physics topics required for a double major at these universities. However, I taught myself much of this material, so I do not have official coursework in these fields from my previous university.

I would like to get credit for these major requirements so I can focus on taking classes in new (hopefully graduate) topics.

**Question**

Is it in the norm to request an exam to place out of a major requirement?

If so, is there any protocol for making such a request?

If not, are there other methods of getting out of major requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the US, AP or CLEP are an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some universities will permit this and have regular procedures. For others it might be an exceptional case. One place to start is to go to the department office and enquire. Another is a (possible) enrollment counseling office that has responsibility for placing transfers.

You might wind up with a few oral exams, however, so be prepared for that. The oral "exam" might just be an interview with a faculty member who explores what you have done and asks a few questions.

The only other way I can think of is to have transcripts of very similar courses, but you likely don't have that.

You probably don't get traditional "credit" for the courses, but a notation that you didn't need to take them. Grades are not likely, but there may be exceptions.

But each institution will have different procedures (in the US, at least).

Comment: @ Buffy Thanks for the response. I now believe I have a better idea on how to proceed. I may be asking too much here, but if credit towards a major is not offered for the courses I test out of, what is the replacement? Can I substitute a course I placed out of for another? Or is this school-specific?

Comment: I think the likely thing is that you would take a more advanced course if it is part of the major. For other, general education, courses, it could be institution dependent.

Comment: @ Buffy Would it then generally be frowned upon to propose a substitute course that is in the math/physics department but is not a major requirement, such as a graduate course?

Comment: You can ask of course

Comment: @ Buffy That's fair. I appreciate the help.